# How to hide or make it read only content type column only for Document Set Content Types

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, document-set

I want to be able to manage Document Content Types from a SharePoint Online library but I don't want the user to manage the Document Set Content Types. Can this be achieved and how?

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to have a different permision level (edit) for yourself and different permission level (contribute) for "the other users".

more here:

https://sharepointmaven.com/edit-vs-contribute-permission-levels-in-sharepoint-online/

or here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels#default-permission-levels